# Protected Android industry app

Tags: android, android-security

We have some Android apps are installed to our company smartphones with Android 7.

Sometimes our users uninstall those apps or making dificult to use it properly.

We asked our Android developers investigate posibility to prevent users to

1. Uninstall app
2. Stop services
3. Turn off Mobile Data or WIFI services

They answerd is impossible to do it at all.

Well... We like to configure Android devices for special company usage with strong restrictions as described above.

Is it possible to archive it using Android SDK? Is any posibility to do it?

Thank you!

--------- UPDATE #1 ------------------------------------------------

**I gues the best idea is to use Android Device Administration API https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html**

and mix it with approaches described

[Require a password to uninstall/remove application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221534/require-a-password-to-uninstall-remove-application)

[Android - Start service on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot/7690600#7690600)

[Application without app launcher icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809309/application-without-app-launcher-icon)

I mean once we install custom enterprise app APK we can also install app/service without ICON and is having 'special' name so user cannot by his knowlidge identify it by icon (no icon at all) and by service name (it should mimic a native Android Service). This non-icon-service should listen activites user does and prevent to execute him to do dangerous activity by activating PIN/PASSWORD screen. Well user shouldnt know PIN/PASSWORD.

> This kind of workaround looks likes a legal fishing way to avoid
>   breaking stuff we need like
>
> 1. Uninstall app
> 2. Stop services
> 3. Turn off Mobile Data or WIFI services

**---------- UPDATE #2 --------------------------------**

> The conclusion is the only including app in firmware is only way to
>   make app undeletable 100%. There is no other options.

**---------- UPDATE #3 and the last one ------------------**

[Utilize and complement Android's enterprise features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455942/utilize-and-complement-androids-enterprise-features/48456766#48456766)

Comment: Basically the answer is **no**, since you should not be able to prevent users from uninstalling apps. But there are some services, which are called `MDM systems`, who's aim is to manage users' apps. Investigate that way.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Good catch Vlad! Pls provide more details.

Comment: you can make the apps system apps in that way only rooted devices can uninstall the apps

Comment: @Zacktamondo It sounds good. I found a similar approach here https://www.androidauthority.com/install-user-app-as-system-app-how-to-93522/ Would you mind post your answer with some links how to do it for Android 7 and Android Studio 3 please?

Comment: The feature you need is called ["device admin"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html). It is indeed possible to place some restrictions on device usage, including inability to remove the "admin" app. Note, however, that there can only be *one* active admin app at given time.

Comment: @user1643723 Please provide more info about it. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](https://www.androidauthority.com/install-user-app-as-system-app-how-to-93522/) you posted in the comment says it all.

All you have to do first is to root the devices and then make the your apps `System apps` using (`ES file explorer, Titanium backup, /system/app mover ★ ROOT ★ ...`) and then unroot the devices.

Also you can you a parental control app like (`Norton Family Parental Control , Net Nanny , Qustodio Parental Control , Mobicip ....`) check this [link](https://www.pcmag.com/roundup/342731/the-best-parental-control-apps-for-your-phone).

As for a legal and secure way you can always contact the company and ask to include your apps as `system apps`.

Comment: What about this approach `https://www.androidauthority.com/install-user-app-as-system-app-how-to-93522/`  Installing a System App via ADB ?

Comment: it can be done too

Comment: But seriously I buy 100 smartphones for company employers I need to protect app somehow. Should be an official and legal way to do it. Is it legal way?

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer I improved my answer please check it.