# Utilize and complement Android's enterprise features

Tags: android, android-enterprise-features

As Google says here https://developer.android.com/work/guide.html

> As an Android developer, you can deploy devices and apps to employees
>   and keep your corporate data secure.

And also here https://developer.android.com/work/index.html

> Android in the Enterprise Develop apps for the enterprise that take
>   advantage of the security and management features built into Android.

But this set of webpages does not provide detailed step by step explanation whaht is **ENTERPRISE PROFILE CONFIGURATION** and **HOW TO USE IT**?

Let's say I need to install couple of enterprise applications and prevent them to be uninstalled via enterprose profile for instance.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: if you go further in the documentation there are some guidelines on how to do it or use it.
https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations.html
https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles.html

Comment: @Umair It is unclear how it is useful. And need to answer to this question `Let's say I need to install couple of enterprise applications and prevent them to be uninstalled via enterprose profile for instance.`

Comment: well to meet your requirements, you should take a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

and also at this question they may be closest to what you want to do.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540002/how-to-prevent-an-application-from-being-uninstalled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 hours of investigation I found only one light and elegant way to archive my goal.

> CUSTOM ANDROID LAUNCHER DEVELOPMENT
>
> This custom launcher could contains
>
> 1. One screen only with predefined icons.
> 2. No icons to see all apps or settings.
> 3. Button to add/remove apps to main screen which is protected by internal launcher password (Only admin knows password or it can be
>      server-side AUTH).

**So employers take this preconfigured smartphone and do what they must according their work task while are restricted by launcher possibilities. Also they cannot uninstall it at all.**

Comment: I think you are saying that on the employee phone only one app will run and user won't be able to exit it in any way possible. 
Only the admin will be able to do that.

Comment: Yes. The "Enterprise Launcher" and well we can start at background lots of enterprise services as well. So users will never stop  or uninstall them.